# Apache RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite the following URL:

```
http://example.com/folder/subfolder/filename
```

to

```
http://example.com/folder/subfolder/filename.txt
```

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/folder/subfolder/(.*)(|/)$  /folder/subfolder/$1.txt      [R=302,L]
```

However this makes to rewrites go into a loop so I will get:

```
/folder/subfolder/filename.txt.txt.txt.txt (etc)
```

Any idea how to make my rewrite rule work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.txt$
```

before the rule. I cannot test this at this very moment, but I'm sure, this is what you need.